# Solving a differential equation using symbolic computation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symbolic-computation

I have the initial value problem

$$\ddot x (t) + k \sin(x(t)) = 0$$

with initial conditions $x(0) =: x_0 $ and $\dot x (0) =: v_0$. Using Maxima I should check that

$$\frac{1}{2}(\dot x (t))^2 + k (1-\cos(x(t))) = \text{const}$$

So I though I will simply find solution and substitute. But the solution I got is ugly

$$\pm \frac{\displaystyle\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{k\cos(x)-\%k1k}}}}{\sqrt{2}}=t+\%k2$$

I haven't used my initial condition about $x$ and $\dot x$ because I am not sure how?

I will be more than glad for help.

Comment: Of course we expect the solution of a second-order ODE to have two arbitrary constants.  Here they are called %k1 and %k2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+k\sin(x)=0$$

$2\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\frac{dx}{dt}+2k\sin(x)\frac{dx}{dt}=0 \quad\to\quad \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2-2k\cos(x)=c_1$

$x(0)=x_0$ and $x'(0)=v_0$ $\to$ $(v_0)^2-2k\cos(x_0)=c_1$
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2-2k\cos(x)=(v_0)^2-2k\cos(x_0)$$

$$dt=\pm \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2k\cos(x)-2k\cos(x_0)+(v_0)^2}}$$

$$t=\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{2k\cos(\chi)-2k\cos(x_0)+(v_0)^2}}$$

$$ t= \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\left( F\left(\frac{x}{2}\:\Bigg|\:m\right) - F\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\:\Bigg|\:m\right)\right)$$
$m=\frac{4k}{v_0^2+2k-2k\cos(x_0)}$ and $F\:$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind.

The inverse function $x(t)$ can be expressed in terms of Jacobi amplitude function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html

In ADDITION to my first answer :

Reading again the question, especially this point :

> Using Maxima I should check that
>   $\frac{1}{2}(\dot x (t))^2 + k (1-\cos(x(t))) = \text{const}$

If that's all the problem, the analytic answer is easy :

Multiply the ODE by $\dot x(t)$ and integrate :

$$\ddot x (t)\dot x(t) + k \sin(x(t))\dot x(t) = 0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\dot x(t)\right)^2 -k \cos\left(x(t)\right) = c$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\dot x(t)\right)^2 +k\left(1- \cos\left(x(t)\right) \right)=k+c $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\dot x(t)\right)^2 +k\left(1- \cos\left(x(t)\right) \right) = \text{const} $$
That is what it was asked to show.

So, you just have to make the symbolic computer doing the same than what was handly done above.

Comment: I haven't heard about Jacobi amplitude function it all seems to be too much complicated. Maybe we don't need to calculete it? Ale we care is to show that $$\frac{1}{2}(\dot x (t))^2 + k (1-\cos(x(t))) = \text{const}$$ so maybe there is another way? Also I don't need to calculate on my own. I am told to use Maxima but i don't know how to get x from solution:$$\pm \frac{\displaystyle\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{k\cos(x)-\%k1k}}}}{\sqrt{2}}=t+\%k2$$

Comment: If you want the analytical solution $x(t)$ , expressed with a formula, it will necessarily involve the Jacobi elliptic function. If it is not what is asked for, we cannot help you without knowing exactly what is the textual wording of the problem.

Comment: See the addition to my first answer. Is it what you have to do ?

Comment: Thanks that was the problem :) I will try with this aproach now, looks more doable then previous one.